# Code CS1501 No everload meathod for 'connect' takes 1 arguments

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Hello I'm writing a bot for discord and I'm using this code and can't figure out how to fix this CS1501 code. The tutorial I'm using doesn't cover it and as far as i can tell the code is the same.

```
internal class MyBot
{
    class Mybot
    {
        DiscordClient discord;

        public Mybot()
        {
            discord = new DiscordClient(x =>
            {
                x.LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info;
                x.LogHandler = Log;
            });

            discord.ExecuteAndWait(async () =>
            {
                await discord.Connect("MjIzNTAzMzU3MTI0MjgwMzIw.CrRxsA.4__tA7Z-XNJ04KbK1HzvjXBzYww﻿");
            });
        }

        private void Log(object sneder, LogMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to check the overloaded `Connect` function, then decide how many and which parameter can be passed.

Comment: How do I go about doing that? I'm brand new to coding and error hunting and everything I read on this reads like alien script.